# Element Not Obeying Vertical-Align: bottom, why?

Tags: vertical-alignment, css

Why doesn't the middle element obey the `vertical-align` rule?

How could i get it to do so?

Example:

```
<div id="outer">
  <!-- why doesn't this obey its inline-block and snap to bottom? -->
  <div id="inner">From The Smiths</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer{
top: 0.452873563218px; 
left: 23.8988505747126px; 
transform: rotate(0deg); 
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); 
width: 284.88275862069px; 
height: 58.8229885057471px; 
z-index: 5; 
font-size: 8.81226053639847px; 
position: absolute; 
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#inner{
top: 0px;  
left: 0px; 
font-family: 'Open Sans'; 
text-align: center; 
vertical-align: bottom; 
color: rgb(140, 149, 157); 
font-weight: 300; 
font-size: 8.81226053639847px; 
position: relative; 
display: inline-block; 
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
height: 10px;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

Link to jsbin: http://jsbin.com/mavuhikifi/2/

Comment: Why on earth are there so many attributes? I can't read your style code from there. You'll have to make a separate stylesheet (or at least a `<style>` element in the head).

Comment: @GeorgePlatko updated per your req

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the outer div to display:table and the inner div to display:table-cell

```css
#outer {
    top: 0.452873563218px;
    left: 23.8988505747126px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    width: 284.88275862069px;
    height: 58.8229885057471px;
    z-index: 5;
    font-size: 8.81226053639847px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
}
#inner {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    font-family:'Open Sans';
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    color: rgb(140, 149, 157);
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 8.81226053639847px;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <!-- why doesn't this obey its inline-block and snap to bottom? -->
    <div id="inner">From The Smiths</div>
</div>
```

Or use absolute/relative positioning as in this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/r2ma9umu/)**.